# Parsing xml document to array using GDataXmlNode in Cocos2d for iPhone

Tags: ios, xml, cocos2d-iphone, xml-parsing

So, I couldn't find any tutorials online for a way to parse an xml document to an array, so I tried to implement it myself in this way:

```
NSMutableArray *data = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];

NSString *filePath = [self dataFilePath:FALSE forWorld:world];
NSLog(@"filePath = %@",filePath);
NSData *xmlData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSError *error;
GDataXMLDocument *doc = [[GDataXMLDocument alloc] initWithData:xmlData options:0 error:&error];
if (doc == nil) {return nil; NSLog(@"xml file is empty!");}
NSLog(@"Loading %@", filePath);

NSArray *dataArray = [doc nodesForXPath:@"//Levels/level" error:nil];
NSLog(@"Array Contents = %@", dataArray);


for (GDataXMLElement *element in dataArray) {
    NSArray *dataArrayContainer= [doc nodesForXPath:@"//Levels/level/data" error:nil];
    NSMutableArray *rowArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    int i=0;
    int j;

    for (GDataXMLElement *element in dataArrayContainer) {
        NSArray *dataPointArray = [element elementsForName:@"p"];
        if (dataPointArray.count > 0 && i <= dataPointArray.count) {
            NSLog(@"current i is %i",i);
            GDataXMLElement *dataArrayElement = (GDataXMLElement *) [dataPointArray objectAtIndex:i];
            NSNumber* dataElement = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[dataArrayElement stringValue] intValue]];
            [data addObject: dataElement];

            i++;
        }
    }
Level *level = [[Level alloc] initWithdata:data];
[levels.levels addObject:level];
}
```

my xml looks like this:

```
<Levels>
<level>
    <name> world1Level1 </name>
    <number> 1 </number>
    <unlocked> 1 </unlocked>
    <cheeses> 0 </cheeses>
    <data>
        <p>3</p><p>9</p><p>6</p><p>9</p><p>3</p><p>1</p><p>0</p><p>15</p><p>25</p><p>0</p><p>0</p>
    </data>
    <blocks>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>1</b> <b>15</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>1</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>1</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>1</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>1</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>1</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>1</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>1</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>1</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
    </blocks>

</level>

<level>
    <name> world1Level2 </name>
    <number> 2 </number>
    <unlocked> 0 </unlocked>
    <cheeses> 0 </cheeses>
    <data>
        <p>3</p><p>9</p><p>6</p><p>9</p><p>3</p><p>1</p><p>0</p><p>15</p><p>25</p><p>0</p><p>0</p>
    </data>
    <blocks>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
    </blocks>

</level>

<level>
    <name> world1Level3 </name>
    <number> 3 </number>
    <unlocked> 0 </unlocked>
    <cheeses> 0 </cheeses>
    <data>
        <p>3</p><p>9</p><p>6</p><p>9</p><p>3</p><p>1</p><p>0</p><p>15</p><p>25</p><p>0</p><p>0</p>
    </data>
    <blocks>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
    </blocks>
</level>

<level>
    <name> world1Level4 </name>
    <number> 4 </number>
    <unlocked> 0 </unlocked>
    <cheeses> 0 </cheeses>
    <data>
        <p>3</p><p>9</p><p>6</p><p>9</p><p>3</p><p>1</p><p>0</p><p>15</p><p>25</p><p>0</p><p>0</p>
    </data>
    <blocks>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
    </blocks>
</level>

<level>
    <name> world1Level5 </name>
    <number> 5 </number>
    <unlocked> 0 </unlocked>
    <cheeses> 0 </cheeses>
    <data>
        <p>3</p><p>9</p><p>6</p><p>9</p><p>3</p><p>1</p><p>0</p><p>15</p><p>25</p><p>0</p><p>0</p>
    </data>
    <blocks>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
    </blocks>
</level>

<level>
    <name> world1Level6 </name>
    <number> 6 </number>
    <unlocked> 0 </unlocked>
    <cheeses> 0 </cheeses>
    <data>
        <p>3</p><p>9</p><p>6</p><p>9</p><p>3</p><p>1</p><p>0</p><p>15</p><p>25</p><p>0</p><p>0</p>
    </data>
    <blocks>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
    </blocks>
</level>

<level>
    <name> world1Level7 </name>
    <number> 7 </number>
    <unlocked> 0 </unlocked>
    <cheeses> 0 </cheeses>
    <data>
        <p>3</p><p>9</p><p>6</p><p>9</p><p>3</p><p>1</p><p>0</p><p>15</p><p>25</p><p>0</p><p>0</p>
    </data>
    <blocks>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
    </blocks>
</level>

<level>
    <name> world1Level8 </name>
    <number> 8 </number>
    <unlocked> 0 </unlocked>
    <cheeses> 0 </cheeses>
    <data>
        <p>3</p><p>9</p><p>6</p><p>9</p><p>3</p><p>1</p><p>0</p><p>15</p><p>25</p><p>0</p><p>0</p>
    </data>
    <blocks>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
    </blocks>
</level>

<level>
    <name> world1Level9 </name>
    <number> 9 </number>
    <unlocked> 0 </unlocked>
    <cheeses> 0 </cheeses>
    <data>
        <p>3</p><p>9</p><p>6</p><p>9</p><p>3</p><p>1</p><p>0</p><p>15</p><p>25</p><p>0</p><p>0</p>
    </data>
    <blocks>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
    </blocks>
</level>

<level>
    <name> world1Level10 </name>
    <number> 10 </number>
    <unlocked> 0 </unlocked>
    <cheeses> 0 </cheeses>
    <data>
        <p>3</p><p>9</p><p>6</p><p>9</p><p>3</p><p>1</p><p>0</p><p>15</p><p>25</p><p>0</p><p>0</p>
    </data>
    <blocks>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
    </blocks>
</level>

<level>
    <name> world1Level11 </name>
    <number> 11 </number>
    <unlocked> 0 </unlocked>
    <cheeses> 0 </cheeses>
    <data>
        <p>3</p><p>9</p><p>6</p><p>9</p><p>3</p><p>1</p><p>0</p><p>15</p><p>25</p><p>0</p><p>0</p>
    </data>
    <blocks>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
    </blocks>
</level>

<level>
    <name> world1Level12 </name>
    <number> 12 </number>
    <unlocked> 0 </unlocked>
    <cheeses> 0 </cheeses>
    <data>
        <p>3</p><p>9</p><p>6</p><p>9</p><p>3</p><p>1</p><p>0</p><p>15</p><p>25</p><p>0</p><p>0</p>
    </data>
    <blocks>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
    </blocks>
</level>

<level>
    <name> world1Level13 </name>
    <number> 13 </number>
    <unlocked> 0 </unlocked>
    <cheeses> 0 </cheeses>
    <data> </data>

</level>

<level>
    <name> world1Level14 </name>
    <number> 14 </number>
    <unlocked> 0 </unlocked>
    <cheeses> 0 </cheeses>
    <data>
        <p>3</p><p>9</p><p>6</p><p>9</p><p>3</p><p>1</p><p>0</p><p>15</p><p>25</p><p>0</p><p>0</p>
    </data>
    <blocks>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
    </blocks>
</level>

<level>
    <name> world1Level15 </name>
    <number> 15 </number>
    <unlocked> 0 </unlocked>
    <cheeses> 0 </cheeses>
    <data>
        <p>3</p><p>9</p><p>6</p><p>9</p><p>3</p><p>1</p><p>0</p><p>15</p><p>25</p><p>0</p><p>0</p>
    </data>
    <blocks>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
    </blocks>
</level>

<level>
    <name> world1Level16 </name>
    <number> 16 </number>
    <unlocked> 0 </unlocked>
    <cheeses> 0 </cheeses>
    <data>
        <p>3</p><p>9</p><p>6</p><p>9</p><p>3</p><p>1</p><p>0</p><p>15</p><p>25</p><p>0</p><p>0</p>
    </data>
    <blocks>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
    </blocks>
</level>

<level>
    <name> world1Level17 </name>
    <number> 17 </number>
    <unlocked> 0 </unlocked>
    <cheeses> 0 </cheeses>
    <data>
        <p>3</p><p>9</p><p>6</p><p>9</p><p>3</p><p>1</p><p>0</p><p>15</p><p>25</p><p>0</p><p>0</p>
    </data>
    <blocks>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
    </blocks>
</level>

<level>
    <name> world1Level18 </name>
    <number> 18 </number>
    <unlocked> 0 </unlocked>
    <cheeses> 0 </cheeses>
    <data>
        <p>3</p><p>9</p><p>6</p><p>9</p><p>3</p><p>1</p><p>0</p><p>15</p><p>25</p><p>0</p><p>0</p>
    </data>
    <blocks>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
    </blocks>
</level>

<level>
    <name> world1Level19 </name>
    <number> 19 </number>
    <unlocked> 0 </unlocked>
    <cheeses> 0 </cheeses>
    <data>
        <p>3</p><p>9</p><p>6</p><p>9</p><p>3</p><p>1</p><p>0</p><p>15</p><p>25</p><p>0</p><p>0</p>
    </data>
    <blocks>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
    </blocks>
</level>

<level>
    <name> world1Level20 </name>
    <number> 20 </number>
    <unlocked> 0 </unlocked>
    <cheeses> 0 </cheeses>
    <data>
        <p>3</p><p>9</p><p>6</p><p>9</p><p>3</p><p>1</p><p>0</p><p>15</p><p>25</p><p>0</p><p>0</p>
    </data>
    <blocks>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
        <row> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> <b>0</b> </row>
    </blocks>
</level>
</Levels>
```

However I only want the array data to contain values from one Level node at a time, obviously the problem with this is that when I write: `NSArray *dataArrayContainer= [doc nodesForXPath:@"//Levels/level/data" error:nil];` it puts data nodes from all level nodes into the array dataArrayContainer, which is not at all what I want it to only put data nodes from the currently selected level. However I can't seem to find any way to do this, I can't find anywhere online where it shows how to send a variable to nodesForXPath so I don't see how this is ever going to be possible :/ A hand anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you all the nodes under data for all elements (level) with the element "name" with the value "world1Level20":

```
NSArray *nodes = [xmlDoc nodesForXPath:@"//*[contains(name,'world1Level20')]/data" error:nil];
```

Comment: Yes this is brilliant for finding the nodes under each level however this would mean I would have to write a parsing statement for each level individually to add the data elements to the required array, I have been looking into another method, as I realised it is possible to navigate further down the document relative to a GDataXMLElement.

Comment: im not sure I understand what you are trying to do. Can't you just create an array of your level names, iterate through them and then dynamically generate the xpath statement with them? something like [NSString stringWithFormat:@"//*[contains(name,'%@')]/data", levelName]

Comment: Ahhhh you see now that would work! Thankyou very much! Hadn't though of creating an NSString and then sending that to nodesForXPath!

Comment: Ooooop sorry completely forgot until I just logged on!